# Get GitHub repository detail info, branches info with default_branch's all sources in one API request?

Tags: javascript, github-api, github-api-v3

I can use these three API to get those result.

- Repo info API: `GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/`
- Branch API: `GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/branches`
- Tree API: `GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/git/trees/{tree_sha}?recursive=true`

But it will cost me three API calls. Maximum limit is 60 per hour.

Is there a way to get all those result in one request?

Comment: This might not cover everything those other endpoints cover, but maybe you could use the [events api](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/activity#events). I remember also having this same kind of problem, and events were a workaround for me. Caveat is that the data you want to retrieve can't be too old.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But events api didn't work for me. I scraped the mentioned data from html page as a workaround.